# Can I use Apache 2.2.15 with mod_rewrite enabled?

Tags: 8, installation

I currently am running Centos 6 which only comes with Apache 2.2.15.  Yeah, I know it is about time for me to upgrade...  I get the following warning:

> The minimum version of Apache needed to run Drupal without mod_rewrite
>   enabled is 2.2.16. See the enabling clean URLs page for more
>   information on mod_rewrite.

I have mod_rewrite enabled. Am I okay as is? I don't care about pretty URLs at the moment as I am just learning about Drupal, and will upgrade my OS someday soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can go with Apache 2.2.15 as long as you have mod_rewrite enabled (so you'll have pretty urls).

From Drupal issue [Regression fix: allow Drupal 8 to work without Apache mod_rewrite](https://www.drupal.org/node/2382513)

> Apache 2.2.16 is only required if mod_rewrite is NOT enabled

Comment: Beat me to it.  The specific comment is https://www.drupal.org/node/2382513#comment-9379857, which has to do with `FallbackResource` being added.

Comment: Thanks Sanzante.  I definitely have mod_rewrite enabled (I tested it using `exit('<pre>'.print_r(apache_get_modules(),1).'</pre>');`  I can't get past the Drupal configuration page, however.  Do I need to set up rewrite rules before I configure Drupal?

Comment: IIRC, that is only presented if `mod_rewrite` isn't working.  It is possible to have the module be present, but disallowed per server-config.

Comment: @MPD  Thanks!  I typically never use `.htaccess`, and didn't have overrides allowed.